# Add textbox value to it's destination

Tags: vba, excel, userform

**Situation**: I'm working on a UserForm with the following Controls:

- Combobox: This is used to pull up a list of names on Sheet2 (Column A) and allows the user to select a name that'll be used for the form. [image: see image of userform]
- TextBox: This is used to add a numerical value. That value will be placed on Sheet2, Column C, and two rows over from the name that's been selected from the combo box
- CommandButton: This button is used to add the numerical value that has been typed into the text box into the cell on Sheet2, two columns over, and two rows over from the cell matching the name that's been choosen from the combobox

Problem: I have the Combobox and Textbox set up correctly but am having trouble creating VBA for the CommandButton to add the text box value to it's destination.

VBA So Far:

```
Private Sub AddButton_Click()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Crystal As Long

Set WS = Worksheets("ParticipantList")

With WS.Range("a2:c300")

    FindColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.Participants.Value, WS.Range("A2:A300"), 1)

    Crystal = Me.NumberOfCryst.Value

    If FindColumn <> "" Then
        With WS.Range("a2:c300")
            Text = Me.NumberOfCryst.Value
            WS.Activate
            FindColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.Participants.Value, WS.Range("A2:A300"), 0)
        End With
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Now obviously this is all over the place and I've made tons of changes and attempts at getting it to work.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You do not use the `Text` for anything. So you need to assign the value of `Text` to a destination (cell).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you're after something like this:

```
Private Sub AddButton_Click()
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Rng = Worksheets("ParticipantList").Range("A2:A300").Find(What:=Me.Participants.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then Rng.Offset(2, 2).Value = Rng.Offset(2, 2).Value + CLng(Me.NumberOfCryst.Text)
End Sub
```

you may also want to add some textbox text validation and be sure the user input a numeric value

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! I highly appreciate your time making this. Do you know how to add in a step to where it's adding that number value to a number that already exists within that cell?

Comment: @Kyle, did you get through it?